# Session logging out in 30 min irrespective of activity

Tags: java, web.xml, session-timeout

I have set <session-timeout> as 30 min in web.xml. If I am not wrong this one supposed to logout the session in 30 min only when the session is inactive. But in my application user is logged out in 30 min irrespective of activity. can anyone please help me with this? I am not where the issue is.

Comment: What have you set as 30 minutes in web.xml? If you've set the session lifetime as 30 minutes, it should be 30 minutes of inactivity, not 30 minutes period (the cookie expiration should be refreshed every request to the server). Try checking the cookie expiration in your browser after a couple of page views and see if it's 30 minutes from that page view or 30 minutes from your first page view.

Comment: I guess that all your activity somehow happens beyond the session. Probably cookies are not send with other activity or something like this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry the text lost in html translation. session-timeout is set to 30 min. Ok sure, I will try the cookie expiration time and see.

Comment: Thank you Alex. How can I make sure if the cookies are sent with other activity?

Comment: Cookies are set for a Domain and a Path; if you perform a request on that domain and path, the (session) cookie is automatically sent by the browser. If your ajax request happens on a path which is totally different from the path where you got your cookie (after a form login for instance) your cookie may never be sent and refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you are not getting a new session with every request.  An easy way to do this is to store an Integer in the session and increment it with every request.  Then add the value of the integer (as an Integer or a String) to the response and display it on the page (display may be adding it it the page as a hidden field if you want).

Comment: I think getting a new session on every request would be very obvious - arguably more obvious that session expiry after 30 minutes (assuming the user may stop usage within the 30 minute period).

Answer (score 0):

There can be lots of reasons that may cause unexpected session timeout and without further information, all I can give is just some pointers and suggestions.

1. Do you use a cluster? if you do, please check your load balancer's algorithm and settings. Does the user request being forwarded to a different server in the cluster after 30 minutes? Do you have session replication configured in your cluster? Another easy way to make sure that load balancer is not the culprit is to shut down all other servers in the cluster except one. Thus the requests are guaranteed to be sent to the same server. Then you can check if the 30 minutes timeout irrespective of user activities still happens. Server access log might also helps you to see if the user is bounced between servers.
2. If you have any browser plugin such ieHTTPHeaders installed, please check the session cookie sent by each request and to see if there is any change.
3. Another question is that if you change the 30 minutes timeout in web.xml to 15 minutes, does the user timeout every 15 minutes irrespective of user activity?